# How to create a bookmarklet to go to a specific website, wait for the website to load, then set/select options from a dropdown list

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I am looking to automate filtering of data that is managed through a webpage containing multiple dropdown lists.  I have the simple bit of code to navigate to a website and the simple bit of code to set/select options from dropdown lists. However, when I combine them the bookmarklet tries to set the options before the website is fully loaded.  I've tried using a few different things but have not yet been successful.

I have tried to use:

- window.onload...
- window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded'...

but have not had success.  Here are two scripts that are close but do not seem to wait for the full page to load before setting the options:

```
javascript: ( function () {window.location.href = "https://URL";
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
document.getElementsByName('Dropdown1')[0].value="Pending";
document.getElementsByName('Dropdown2')[0].value="Submitted";};})();
```

--OR--

```
javascript: ( function () {  window.onload = function() {
window.location.href = "https://URL";
document.getElementsByName('Dropdown1')[0].value="Pending";
document.getElementsByName('Dropdown2')[0].value="Submitted"
;}
;})()
```

Comment: It's hard to say without any specific detail about the element you want to target, or how it's added to the DOM, but I would suggest you use a MutationObserver

Comment: Thank you. Here is a more clear example using the dropdowns in the website https://www.analysisfromdata.com/bookmarklets.   I need a bookmarklet that will navigate to the webpage and set the Favorite Season dropdown in the page to Winter.  Here is the raw bookmarklet with no management for the loading of the page:
javascript: ( function () {
  window.location.href ='https://www.analysisfromdata.com/bookmarklets';
  document.getElementsByTagName('select')[3].value="winter";
})();